# multiple uibutton execute same function in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'm building an application that contain many buttons (generated dynamically). All the buttons should execute the same function when pressed. My question is how to know which button has been pressed when the function is called, in order to perform the correct job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button instance that sends an action message to your action handler will be the `sender` parameter passed to the handler. Just compare this against the button instances you have stored.

Alternatively, and slightly kludgy, use the `tag` field of UIView (the superclass of `UIButton`) to differentiate your buttons, and check the tag of `sender`.

Comment: I'm not sure what more clarification I can give without writing it for you. You are presumably storing the `UIButton`s you're creating. When the action method is called, just compare `sender` against each button to find the one that was pressed. (This comment, left here, is a reply to a deleted comment by the author asking for clarification).

Answer (score 1):

Try identifying the sender by a tag on the function that is being executed. That way you will know which button was pressed. You can assign the tag the moment you generate the buttons dynamically.

Optionally you could use a NSDictionary to save all the button tags that are being generated or an Array and then use it accordingly.

Comment: any clarification? because i have this idea in my mind by i don't know how to make it :(